# How to profile an eclipse application in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, profiling

I developed a plugin in Eclipse. But it has some performance problems.  I want to profile my plugin to find some hooks. I searched and found `TPTP`, but it doesn't work in Eclipse Indigo. Is there any other eclipse plugin available for profiling an `Eclipse Application/Java Process`? I am running my plugin using `Run/Debug as eclipse application`.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an Eclipse program is still a Java program, you can use any normal Java profiler. After taking a measurement, you only need to filter the results for the package names of your plugin. I've done very good performance analysises of different Java programs (Swing, Eclipse plugins, ...) using the [Yourkit Java Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/). It has a full feature trial license for commercial use and you can get full licenses for free when working on open source projects.

Answer (score 3):

[JProfiler](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/06/jprofilers-ide-integrations.html) has an eclipse plugin that can profile eclipse applications from within eclipse. See [this screen cast](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/06/jprofilers-ide-integrations.html) to see the JProfiler eclipse plugin in action.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Comment: We've used JProfiler successfully for years to profile our RCP app.